# Vim buffer name autocompletion not working after first directory

Tags: autocompletion, gvim

I have a problem with Vim Autocompletion behavior for buffer names.

**Target Soft/OS**

I'm using gVim without plugins on Windows 10

**What I would like to do**

Assuming we have a file tree like :

```
+---- a 
+---- b
|     +---- c
|     +---- d
|     +---- e0
|     +---- e
|           +----f
|           +----g
```

When I'm searching for a buffer name, here is the behavior I would like :

- `:b <Tab>`   => List `a`, `b/` or every files in the cwd, not all buffers names if possible
- `:b b<Tab>`  => `:b b/`
- `:b b/<Tab>` => List `c`, `d`, `e0`, `e/`
- `:b a/e<Tab>` => List `e0`, `e/` so I can chose the right path
- `:b a/e/<Tab>` => List `f/`, `g/`
  and so on

**What I have tried**

```
set wildmode=longest:list, full
```

If I want to find the file "Core/types.h", and I have the file "Care/file.h" :

- `:b C<Tab>` => it prints every files when I would prefer to have only one level of information, like `Core/` and `Care/`, not `Core/types.h` and `Care/files.h`, but this is the less important issue
- `:b Co<Tab>` => `:b Core/` (This is nice !)
- `:b Core/t<Tab>` => does nothing ! (Why it's not taking `Core/t` as a wildcard ?)
- `:b ty` => `:b Core/types.h`  (This is nice !)

Could it be because of the way I'm opening all my buffers ? I'm doing `gvim **/*` to load all my source files.

**Basically the problem is that the autocompletion doesn't work after a directory, as `:b ty<Tab>` works but not `:b Core/ty<Tab>`**

Hope I was clear and a solution exist for this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug from vim when using backslash on windows, it can be fixed by using `set shellslash`

I've reported the bug, but setting shellslash is easy and sufficient enough for everyday use.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `:b` is only going to select from the buffers you have open. It sounds to me like you want the edit command: `:e`. That should complete on directories and filenames.

If you are looking for a better way to browse your current open buffers try `:ls`. It will list all open buffers making it easy to use `:b x` to go to another. ("x" is a filename or buffer number)

Comment: Exactly ! I want the behavior of the :e edit command, but isn't the edit command opening a new buffer ? Like if I have all my files opened in several different buffers, how can I have the same behavior when I want to switch buffers according to the file name ?

Comment: Yes, `:e` will open a new buffer. `:b` will only search through your current open buffers. I think you can only tab complete file names with `:b`. i.e. if you have a buffer named "foo.txt" you can do `:b f<Tab>` even if you are in a different directory. If you want a better way to see which buffers you have try `:ls`. This brings up a list of all your open buffers. Then while looking at it you can easily do `:b x` where "x" is a filename or buffer number.